# Executing bteq using SSH

Tags: database, bash, shell, ssh, teradata

I try to run a script using SSH. The files are these:

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
export logfile=/home/OprBCIDe/logout.log
export bteqfile=/home/OprBCIDe/test_bteq.btq
echo "Test BTEQ"
bteq < $bteqfile > $logfile  2>&1
```

**test_bteq.btq**

```
.SET ERROROUT STDOUT;
.RUN FILE = /home/OprBCIDe/logon.ini
.EXPORT data file=/home/OprBCIDe/sample.csv
.SET SEPARATOR '|'
SELECT * FROM ds_edw_temp.TEST SAMPLE 100;
.EXPORT reset
.LOGOFF;
.EXIT;
```

The **logon.ini** file has the credentials for Teradata.

When I run **test.sh** file in the local machine, works without problems. But, when I use SSH, the command return this in the **logout.log**

```
CLI:Message catalog open failed!: No such file or directory
The file "errmsg.cat" cannot be opened.
There may be problems with your installation.
 *** CLI error: -1 Message Not Found!
 *** Return code from CLI is: -1
 *** Error: Fatal error from CLI.
 ***        Program exiting!

 *** Exiting BTEQ...
 *** RC (return code) = 8
```

I search the problem with `errmsg.cat`, but I not found nothing specified with Teradata.

**EDIT:**

I found the solution. Only export `COPERR` in `test.sh` with the `errmsg.cat` location on the remote file system.

Comment: Sounds like BTEQ isn't correctly installed on your remote server. What happens if you just try to run bteq from the command line?

Comment: Btw.: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Set the COPERR environment variable to point to the location of the errmsg.cat file. That won't solve any underlying issue but should at least give you a better error message. Or explicitly source a .profile in the ssh session.

Comment: @Andrew if I run the bteq in the local machine, runs without problems

Comment: @Fred that variable I will set in bteq file or sh file?

Comment: That would be in the shell script. See also [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332531) about profile initialization for ssh sessions.

Comment: @Fred thanks. I was able to fix the problem.